# Do large reverted git commits get pushed?

Tags: git, git-revert

I added some large files to my repo and then the push failed (commit 1). I decided I could live without the large files on the remote, so I reverted the commit in my local repo, this is showing up as commit 2 that reverts commit 1. Now any push still fails.

1. Does a push try to still upload the file because both commits are in the history?
2. Would `git reset --hard` to the commit just before commit 1 solve the problem, e.g. would the push ignore commit 1 and 2?

Comment: If you reset to before the first commit, then yes. Perhaps you should first make a copy of your local working folder and repository and experiment. I'm assuming your first commit contains stuff you still want to commit so perhaps a soft reset and cleaning up the index is more what you want?

Comment: @Lasse - yeah, I made backups of the files before doing a reset --hard so I wouldn't lose anything. I just did a --dry-run after the reset --hard and I think it works, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes. 2. Yes.

The reason it's this way is because if some other user checked out commit 1, they would then have the large file on their local file system, so it must exist in the history.

Resetting to the commit before solves it, or, if you've already made further commits and don't want to cherry pick them back in afterwards, you could just interactive rebase, and squash commit 1 and 2 together. In your case reset is probably easiest, but rebase might be cleaner had the revert commit not been in order, say, it was commit 5. During the interactive rebase you can reorder commit 5 to happen right after commit 1, and squash it up into commit 1 (or both 1 and 5 into the previous commit). As usual in Git, There are many ways to skin this cat.